# Kendo UI ComboBox : Automatic Load On Demand

Tags: telerik, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-combobox

Initially we are using Telerik ASP.NET combo box. For this having load on demand option ( [link](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/loadondemand/wcf/defaultcs.aspx)). Now we are moving to Kendo UI combo box.
This combo box doesn't contain all options (which are present in telerik asp.net combobox) like Load on demand , ShowMoreResultsBox.. etc.

Could you please provide solution for updating item on Load on demand

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
         .Name("fabric")
         .Filter("contains")
         .Placeholder("Select fabric...")
         .DataTextField("Text")
         .DataValueField("Value")
         .DataSource(source =>
             source.Read(read =>
                     {
                         read.Url("http://localhost:59590/api/Search/LoadonDemand");
                     }).ServerFiltering(true))
         .HighlightFirst(true)
         .IgnoreCase(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the post for this on Kendo Premium forums itself. Just updating so that SO also has its update: **[Update items for ComboBox with Load on demand](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-complete-for-asp-net-mvc/combobox/update-items-for-combobox-with-load-on-demand-.aspx)**

Just copying their reply.
1st reply

> Basically to achieve the "Load on demand" behavior you should also set
>   the "AutoBind" option to false - that way the ComboBox will request
>   the data only when requested by the user. Additionally you can modify
>   the server to restrict the response to for example 5 records. That way
>   the ComboBox will load only 5 records, related to current search text
>   on demand.

2nd reply

> I'm afraid that loading items on demand inside the ComboBox result
>   drop-down currently is not supported out of the box and the solution
>   from my previous reply should be used instead. Also please note that
>   the KendoUI UserVoice already have such idea added and you can vote
>   for it here (most voted ideas are included in next KendoUI releases).